# count relations inside loop in twig

Tags: php, symfony, one-to-many, twig

I use Symfony2 and twig templating. Think of the Q&A exact same as stackoverflow. There are list of questions with the count of score, answers, views and so on. How to count the answers of the qeustions inside loop in twig? There are OneToMany relation between Question and Answer tables.

```
{% for question in questions %}
    <li>{{ question.score }}</li>
    <li>{# there should be the count // count($question->getAnswers()) #}</li>
    <li>{{ question.view }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Or if there is any better way to achieve this, I am open to suggestions.

Comment: I think this was the 200,000th PHP question on Stack Overflow. Congratulations!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This will print the count:

```
{{ question.answers|length }}
```

Comment: Over here it says: The filter "length " does not exist.

Do i have to activate that filter somewhere?

Comment: Using this syntax still throws query and retrieves all the documents to memory. We just need to throw count query in Mongodb Doctrine ODM. Any idea how to achieve it?