# symfony2.1: count doctrine collection in twig template

Tags: php, templates, doctrine-orm, twig, symfony-2.1

I have a doctrine entity that has a collection of entities (*children*). 
Now i want to count the entities and print out the count.
Something like this:

```
<div class="item">
 <h1>{{ object.name }}</h1>
 <div class="childrenCount">children {% count (object.children) %}</div>
</div>
```

I found some examples which didn't work ([*like using a "count" filter*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9598577/count-relations-inside-loop-in-twig) which resulted in a "filter not found" error).

Comment: `object.children|length` should have worked, what's the exact error message?

Comment: The Message is 'Filter "length" not found.'

Comment: In Full: using count it is: The filter "count" does not exist in OurBuyBundle:Mail:bill.html.twig at line 10

Comment: There's no `count` filter, but there is a `length` filter. Which version of twig are you using?

Comment: Found out "count" actually doesn't exist: http://forum.symfony-project.org/viewtopic.php?t=37282&p=123891
And the "length" hing was a typo - how "embarrassing".

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As found [here](http://forum.symfony-project.org/viewtopic.php?t=37282&p=123891), with doctrine there is the option to use the "count" method when handling a doctrine collection. Otherwise you can use the "length" Filter.

Example Code:

```
<ul class="summary">
  <li> {{ object.children | length }}</li>
  <!-- or, use the count method of doctrine collections directly -->
  <li> {{ object.children.count }}</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use "length"
example:

```
{% if users|length > 10 %}
...
{% endif %}
```

See documentation: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/length.html

Comment: Soooo ... just like in the already accepted answer above? ;-)